# Subversion 2012 server issue

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, tortoisesvn

When i paste my subversion url "https://DomainName/svn/ProjectName/" in the browser , it has been changed to "https://DomainName/!/#ProjectName/". But subversion url is been working perfectly when accessing the project through svncheckout .please provide me a guidance to resolve this problem asap.

Comment: What is causing it to change?  The browser, or a webserver-issued redirect?

Comment: it happens while redirecting browser

Answer (score 2):

This is feature of [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/), not Subversion itself: it automatically redirects you to [rich web interface](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/) with syntax highlighting, log viewer etc. You may find Subversion URL by clicking on "Checkout" icon on top-right:
[image]

You may disable redirecting to rich web interface if needed:

1. Start VisualSVN Server Manager
2. Select Properties in context menu for root node
3. Remove "Enable automatic redirection from the legacy web interface" checkbox on "Web Interface" page.